# How can I normalize a matrix in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix

I need to divide each matrix element (i, j) by the sqrt of the product of the diagonal elements (i, i) and (j, j)

in other words for all **i** and **j** I need to perform:

```
mat(i, j) = mat(i, j)/sqrt(mat(i,i)*mat(j,j))
```

So the matrix:

```
4   0   12                 
0   1   1
12  0   9
```

turns into:

```
1   0   2                 
0   1   1
2   0   1
```

What I have so far is a list of row/column index pairs with a weight that I convert into a CoordinateMatrix (and later RowMatrix). I extract the diagonal by filtering elements where row == column.

What's the best way to implement this elementwise division?

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry, RowMatrix}
import scala.math.sqrt

val pairs = Array((0,0,4.0), (0,2,12.0), (1,1,1.0), (2,0,12.0), (2,2,9.0))
val pairs_rdd = sc.parallelize(pairs)

val diagonal = pairs_rdd.filter(r => r._1 == r._2).map(r => (r._2, sqrt(r._3)))

val matrixEntries = pairs_rdd.map(r => MatrixEntry(r._1, r._2, r._3))

val coordinateMatrix: CoordinateMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(matrixEntries)
val rowMatrix: RowMatrix = coordinateMatrix.toRowMatrix()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems none of the MLLib matrix helper-classes can really assist here, so the only way out seems to be manual joining of your matrix with the diagonal you've created (once by `i`, once by `j`):

```
val diagonal: RDD[(Long, Double)] = pairs_rdd.filter(r => r._1 == r._2).map(r => (r._2, r._3))

val result = matrixEntries
  .keyBy(_.i).join(diagonal).values     // join by i coordinate
  .keyBy(_._1.j).join(diagonal).values  // join by j coordinate
  .map { case ((e, di), dj) => MatrixEntry(e.i, e.j, e.value / sqrt(di * dj)) }
```